# Checking equality of two expressions in WolframCloud

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I want to check if two expressions are equal to each other.

For example 3a+5b === 5b+3a should return 'true'.

I'm trying to use a function:

```
CloudDeploy[
    APIFunction[
        {
            "x" ->Restricted["SemanticExpression", All, Automatic,"equalityTestingContext`"], 
            "y" ->Restricted["SemanticExpression", All, Automatic,"equalityTestingContext`"]
        },
        TrueQ[Simplify[#x == #y]] &
        ],
    Permissions -> "Public"
]
```

This is returning true for given example but fails for checking for example
5aewq+3(b^3) === 3(b^3)+5aqwe, returning 'No result — at least one parameter could not be interpreted'.

What should be changed in above code to allow comparison of more complex expressions? Maybe 'Restricted' interpreter?

Comment: Interesting, so my test cases are bad, right? Every string with length > 3 will be treated as a variable name?

Comment: It's how my code behaves. When I insert the '*' between letters, everything is fine. I'll try to do this outside wolfram before sending the requests. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the interpreter construes `5a` as `5*a` but `aqwe` as a 4-letter variable name and not the same as `aewq`.

I guess that it (the interpreter) follows the practice, common to many programming languages, of regarding an alphanumeric string beginning with a letter as the name of an entity of some sort but parses a string beginning with a digit as a multiplication with the sign omitted.

So `5a` is interpreted as `5*a`, and `123.45a` is interpreted as `123.45*a`, but strings such as `a`, `ab`, `abc`, `a1`, `a2c` are all interpreted as entity names.  All of this, in particular the interpretation of `2a` as `2*a` is consistent with the way that Mathematica / The Wolfram Language interprets input.